# What is the meaning of "flipping the pref"?

Tags: firefox, web-applications

I am trying to figure out the meaning of this phrase. It seems to be the way of dealing with a bug that I found.

Comment: Toggling a boolean preference - maybe (depending on context) twice, as to restore the initial state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `about:config`. Find whatever preference you're looking for and double click it to change the value. If it doesn't already exist you might have to right click and select 'new' to create one.

For more information, see [this MozillaZine article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About%3aconfig) or [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/A_brief_guide_to_Mozilla_preferences).